failed to install taskonomy dataset with omnidata-tools, reporting network failure, no matter with or without proxy
I was trying to download taskonomy dataset to my server (located in China) following the official tutorial of taskonomy website, in order  to form a benchmark for my project. the steps are listed as follows:

install aria2 with command 'sudo apt-get install aria2'
install omnidata-tools with 'pip install omnidata-tools' (pip inside a conda venv of python3.8 in my case)
run the download command 'omnitools.download all --components taskonomy --subset fullplus --dest ../taskonomy/ --connections_total 40 --agree --name *** --email ***', where the error occurs.

environment
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
python 3.8.19
error description

[NOTICE] Confirmation supplied by option '--agree_all'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1354, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
self.connect()
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1418, in connect
super().connect()
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 922, in connect
self.sock = self._create_connection(
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
raise err
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/bin/omnitools.download", line 8, in 
sys.exit(download())
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastcore/script.py", line 119, in _f
return tfunc(**merge(args, args_from_prog(func, xtra)))
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/omnidata_tools/dataset/download.py", line 260, in download
licenses_clickthrough(components, require_prompt=not agree_all, component_to_license=component_to_license, email=email, name=name)
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/omnidata_tools/dataset/download.py", line 87, in licenses_clickthrough
result = urllib.request.urlopen(GOOGLE_FORM_URL.format(name=name, email=email))
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1397, in https_open
return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
File "/home/yhy/.conda/envs/ckf/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1357, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>

I've tried to disable my proxy and to switch to other countries with VPN, but none of the methods worked well, and the error message was basically the same as before.
